# Sequence of intersecting lines

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Suppose we have the following:

- The lines of $y=3x+8$ and $3x+y+4=0$ meet at point $A$.
- Line $L$ goes through point $A$ and point $(7, 11)$.
- Line $L$ meets the $x$ axis at point $B$.
- Line $K$ goes through $B$ and is parallel to the line with equation $y=-4x-3/4$.
- Point $C$ is the intersection of line $K$ and the line with equation $y=-2x$.
- Line $J$ goes through point $C$ and point $A$.
- Line $T$ is perpendicular to line $J$ and goes through $(1, 1)$.
- What is the equation of line T?

The final answer is $3x-7y+4=0$ but I am unsure of how to get there, can anybody help me with this? Much appreciated, thanks! :)

Comment: How far have you managed to get into the problem?

Comment: I was able to get the point B but I got confused at how I carry on from there! :ss

Comment: When you have the point B, because the line $K$ is parallel to $y=-4x - 3/4$, you know that the two lines have the same gradient - as the line is written in the form $y=mx+c$, you then know that what the gradient is ($-4$). You can then substitute in the point $B$ to see what the value of $c$ would be for your line $K$.

Comment: Thank you! How do I then use Line K (y=-4x) to work out Point C? :)

Comment: @Ella Since line K goes through (-4,0) and has slope -4, it has equation $y=-4x-16$; so to find C, you want to set $-2x=-4x-16$ and solve for x, and then use $y=-2x$ or $y=-4x-16$ to get y.

Comment: Thank you for all your help, I worked my way through and got the right answer in the end (with a little help from my Uncle as well) haha :) ×